# Sync, not export, Facebook events with Google Apps calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, synchronization, facebook-events

I have tried this before but didn't get anywhere.

I have a Google Apps account of my own domain that I use for email, calendar and contacts. I sync all of these with my iPhone.

I would like to sync Facebook Events I am attending/maybe attending *only* to another calendar (separate colour) within my Google Apps account calendar. I dont want to have to export to ICS etc. everytime a new event comes up.

I have also tried using http://www.fbcal.com/ but this wouldn't show events with Google Apps.

***[Follow Up Edit]***
Now that the event issue has been sorted out, thanks to eventbusyfix the Facebook Events are working in "other calendars" within my Google Apps calendar. How can you sync this over the air to an iPhone? I only ever see the options to sync your main calendars.

Oh, while I'm at it what about syncing Facebook birthdays as well (not export)?

Comment: At m.google.com/sync I had the option to sync the facebook calendar (read only) as well as my private calendars. They might have added this since you checked?

Comment: Just went back to this problem regarding the other calendars and managed to get it working. Thought I would add my solution here for future references. http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=139206&topic=14252 For google apps users (like myself) follow the second instructions.

Comment: I have tried both EventBusyFix and IcalStripper, but it could only show the event "as-is". But wont update if I create another event in facebook. Is there anyway that I could fix it?

Comment: Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions, not as edits. By the other hand the synchrozation over the air with iPhone might be better handled in and/or with [apple.se].

Comment: @Rubén this question and its follow-up edit is over 13 years old... I doubt the question or any of the answers are even relevant anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on this [here](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/15/how-to-sync-facebook-events-with-google-calendar/). I've not checked that it works, but it seems pretty straight forward. The essence is that instead of importing the calendar, you add the URL of your event feed as a public calendar - here's a summary of the steps:

1. In Facebook click on "Events"
2. Click on "Export Events" and copy the URL
3. In Google Calendar go to "Add" under "Other calendars" and choose "Add by URL"
4. Paste the URL you copied from Facebook and click "Add"

[Update: to make answer more complete]
If you run into issues with private events not showing properly then check out [eventbusyfix.info](http://eventbusyfix.info/). This site acts as an inbetween to clear the private flag and enable Gmail to show them properly (Thanks to prestomation for this tip)
[/Update]

Hope that helps!

Comment: that http://eventbusyfix.info/ doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem with it.

When using the "export" function on Facebook it gives you a wrong link

The format FB gave me was

```
webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=111111111key=AAAAAAAAA-AAAA
```

but it needs to be

```
webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=111111111&key=AAAAAAAAA-AAAA
```

Facebook somehow omits the "&" before "key"

with the "&" it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2013, to sync your facebook calendar with GCal, it's pretty simple.

1. On the events page, click the gear in the top right. Directly next to 'Today'.
2. Click 'Export'
3. Right click 'Upcoming Events' and click Copy URL.
4. Go into Google Calendar and click the arrow next to 'Other Calendars'
5. Click 'Add by URL' and paste the link you copied.

And you're done. Google will sync up with your Facebook events just like that.

If you want to import birthdays, just follow the same steps, instead copying the other hyperlink.