# Export Facebook event directly to Google Calendar?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, facebook-events

Facebook events have an "Export" option which gives you the possibility to either download an .ics file or email the event info.

Given these options, what's the simplest way to add an event to my Google Calendar? Is there perhaps some utility (e.g. Firefox addon or some Linux tool) that handles ics files and directs them to Google?

(Or is it indeed easiest to email the event (to my Gmail) and then click "Add to calendar" from there?)

I don't want to create a separate calendar or anything like that ([as in this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/sync-not-export-facebook-events-with-google-apps-calendar)), and I'd like to export only hand-picked events from Facebook.

Comment: Ah, on a Mac this is very straightforward if you have added your Google Calendar in iCal: simply open the .ics file with iCal and select the right calendar to add it to. I was on Ubuntu when asking this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach would be to either e-mail the event to your Gmail account (as you suggest) or download the file from Facebook and then add it to Google from there.

Comment: Yeah, emailing is not that bad an option, even though an extra step in involved. I actually tried the second way too, saving the .ics file, but couldn't quickly find the way to add it in Google Calendar UI. Can you elaborate how that is done?