# Automatically add a Facebook page's events to Google Calendar

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, facebook-events

Is it possible to add a Facebook page's events to Google Calendar, automatically when the page creates events in the future?

Facebook offers the "subscribed to this page's events" functionality but it simply doesn't work for me (the vast majority of events from the pages I have subscribed to don't appear, very few do, randomly), and also it doesn't add the events the Google Calendar.

Comment: If you could figure out why you're not getting emails for these events and fix that, you could create a gmail filter for these events, which may let you auto-add them to your google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 -  Sync all events

You can add **all** your Facebook Events to Google Calendar. [Details](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3356/47221)

**Side effect**: You get all events (could be a good thing / could be bad)

## Option 2 - Filter these events to just that page

You can use a tool like [ical filter](https://icalfilter.com/) (although I have personally never used it) to filter your ical events, before adding the ical feed, as in *Option 1*.

**Advantage**: you only get events from a particular page of your choosing.

**Downsides**: you have to use a third party service.

Comment: How can I automatically be "interested" in all of a page's events? Their events only appear in my Google Calendar if I am "interested".